# Chat - app (data model) with cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, chat, facebook-messenger, messenger

I need to create chat between users using cassandra.

I have created table chat_messages like this :

```
create table chat_messages(
    user_name text,
    to_user text,
    content text,
    content_id uuid,
    created_at timestamp,
    primary key((user_name,to_user),created_at)
);
```

I want with one select get messages between two users.

```
insert into chat_messages(user_name, to_user, content, content_id, created_at) values('u1','u2','hi u2',uuid(),toTimestamp(now()));
insert into chat_messages(user_name, to_user, content, content_id, created_at) values('u2','u1','hi u1',uuid(),toTimestamp(now()));
```

I want to get  `hi u1` `hi u2`.

Answer (score 0):

With your actual table structure you can use :

```
SELECT content
FROM chat_messages 
WHERE user_name IN ('u1', 'u2') 
  AND to_user IN ('u1', 'u2');
```

But be careful using `IN` in `WHERE` clause because multiple nodes will be query.

Comment: Thanks :) I created table like this :  CREATE TABLE messages ( user_name text, from_user text, to_user text, message text, message_id uuid, conversation_id timeuuid, created_at timestamp, PRIMARY KEY ((user_name, conversation_id), created_at) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC); But now I am saving messages twice.

Comment: Your table structure looks good for your needs. I think it's not a problem to store duplicate messages in your case. Keep in mind one important think about data modeling in Cassandra : design your table structure base on query you want to run.